# How to troubleshoot stalled VPN connection?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I am trying to connect via VPN into my employer's network.

I am already able to do this through my (employer-issued) Macbook, but I want to connect from my home desktop, which runs Debian.

My employer uses Cisco's AnyConnect for VPN, so I installed the Cisco AnyConnect client for Linux.

Whether I use the graphic (vpnui) or the text (vpn) version of the client, the behavior is the same: after I run the command to connect to my employer's VPN server, the client prints out

> Contacting [VPNURL].

...(with "[VPNURL]" replaced by the actual address), and then nothing happens.  This apparent inactivity goes on indefinitely.

The process is actually far from inactive, however.  Until I `kill -9` the process, `top`'s row for it shows ~75% and ~90% for CPU and MEM, respectively.

AFAICT, there's no verbose option for either client.

How can I troubleshoot what is going on?

Comment: In [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213465/cisco-vpn-anyconnect-freezes) the solution was to delete `~/.mozilla/firefox/cert8.db`. Otherwise, if you don't absolutely need to use Cisco Anyconnect client, you can install [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) using `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome`. This will add an Anyconnect compatible option to the VPN GUI under your network settings.

Comment: Do you run AnyConnect as root? As mentioned in @harrymc 's answer, it looks like it only works as root (which would be unsurprising).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to find out what the Cisco AnyConnect client is doing, there
are several tools which might help:

- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), a standard Linux package
  with many tutorials on its website, for tracing network operations.
- [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace), a standard Linux utility
  for tracing system calls and signals.

However, the information you will find out with these utilities will
at most be useful for filing a bug-report with Cisco, but will not
solve the problem.

For a solution, read below for one possible solution and one
possible alternate product.

---

In the Ask Ubuntu
[Cisco vpn AnyConnect freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213465/cisco-vpn-anyconnect-freezes)
was given the advice to remove the file `~/.mozilla/firefox/cert8.db`.
I don't know what is the connection between Firefox and Cisco AnyConnect,
but this worked for the poster and at least one other visitor.

You may get in touch with Cisco AnyConnect Support, but you may also
use alternative and compatible software, the open-source
[OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/),
which describes itself as:

> OpenConnect is an SSL VPN client initially created to support Cisco's
>   AnyConnect SSL VPN. It has since been ported to support the Juniper
>   SSL VPN (which is now known as Pulse Connect Secure), and to the Palo
>   Alto Networks GlobalProtect SSL VPN.
>
> OpenConnect is released under the GNU Lesser Public License, version
>   2.1.
>
> Like vpnc, OpenConnect is not officially supported by, or associated
>   in any way with, Cisco Systems, Juniper Networks, Pulse Secure, or
>   Palo Alto Networks. It just happens to interoperate with their
>   equipment.
>
> Development of OpenConnect was started after a trial of the Cisco
>   client under Linux found it to have many deficiencies

Among the listed deficiencies is:

> Unable to run as an unprivileged user, which would have reduced the severity of the above bug.

So you might try to **run Cisco AnyConnect as root**, to see if it manages
to connect. If this doesn't happen, here is how to use OpenConnect,
as described in a university's article
[Install and configure OpenConnect on Ubuntu for Unimelb Cisco AnyConnect VPN](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/lucasjb/oc.html):

- Open Terminal
- Install OpenConnect from the Ubuntu Universe software repository

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome
  ```
- Open System Settings => Network, click the plus button in the bottom left corner of the window to add a new connection
- Choose Interface: VPN, click on Create...
- Choose Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect), click on Create...

  [image]
- On the VPN tab, complete the connection details
- Confirm that you now have a new VPN connection available, click the off/on switch to enable it

  [image]
- Click the connection icon to logon to the VPN, enter your username and password and click Login

  [image]
- Make a SecureSHell connection to a remote host to confirm that it is available via the VPN interface

  [image]

Comment: Thank you, but your post answers the question "How do I connect to a Cisco AnyConnect VPN from Linux?", which is somewhat different from what I asked.  It is useful information, and I upvoted it, but I hope that it does not discourage others from answering my question.

Comment: Did you try to run Cisco AnyConnect as root? For troubleshooting you could use wireshark (standard package) or `strace`.